# Adding my existing project to Eclipse in linux!

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am very new to linux and also new to use the Eclipse tool...but I have used Visual Studio.I want to know how to add an existing project to eclipse and how to build...inorder to build what all settings has to be done in eclipse.

And also Is there any way that CVS can be used along with eclipse...

Please let me know abt this or refer me any nice tutorial r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have two options to add existing projects into Eclipse:

   **File -> Import.. -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace.
   File -> Import.. -> General -> File System**
2. Eclipse has built-in support for CVS: New Project->CVS -> Projects from CVS

Comment: thanks for you reply James,I have added my project,now I want to build it,build option is disabled Project

Comment: right click on your project folder, choose "Properties" from the popup menu, then check is there any error in "Java Compiler" and "Java Build Path".